# not able to import selenium, even though I have python and pip installed in vscode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

Even though I have Python installed and can confirm it in the command prompt. [image]

VSCode also shows the python installed

[image]

Also I have pip installed in the very same location
[image]

still when I run do import selenium I'm getting this error
[image]

Not sure what am I missing?

Comment: try to go to site-packages root and copy the selenium folder and paste that folder in the root of your project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I uninstalled VS code and Python and then re-installed it. Now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following to check the installation of the module "selenium":

1. Please use the command "`pip --version`" to check whether the source of the module installation tool "pip" is the same as the python displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code: (If they are different, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, and it will automatically enter the selected environment.)

   [image]
2. After the installation is completed in the selected environment, we can use "`pip show selenium`" to check its installation location: `..:\lib\site-packages`

   [image]

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: in this location : C:\Users\AkshayKhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 : if I'm opening the location in VScode and running pip --version ; it shows me pip : 

The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: And this is the same location which shows at the bottom left corner of vscode

Comment: @Akshay Khard -This is because you did not install the module installation tool "pip", (usually installed python comes with "pip".)  How did you install the module "selenium"?

Comment: If I run this command py -m pip --version ; I see this below output : 
C:\Users\AkshayKhard>py -m pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from C:\Users\AkshayKhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Comment: I think I have python and pip installed. However I'm not sure how to run a script which imports selenium. Or from which dir do I run 'pip install selenium'

Comment: @Akshay Khard  -Please check whether the module "selenium" is contained in the folder "\lib\site-packages" in the current python environment. If you want to use "pip" to install the module, it is recommended that you reinstall [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/), which comes with "pip" ", then enter this python environment in the VS Code terminal and use "pip" to install the required modules.

Answer (score -1):

> For using selenium in chrome you have to download selenium chrome
> driver not selenium. So, download the selenium chrome driver from below
> link & Include path in code.
> Note that, You have latest version of chrome

[link]https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

After downloading include path in code like this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: It is already there in the script. 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# /////////////////////////////////////////////// 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://abc.doamin")